# whether we can calculate a limit by knowing the values of two other ones

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

This is **not an exercise** found in a textbook, just a question that arose while I was working on a larger project. The question may sound vague, so let me know If I have skipped on some information. 
So $f, g : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are continuous in an interval that contains zero.
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f^2(x)}{x}=l_1\in \mathbb{R}$$
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-g^2(x)}{x}=l_2\in \mathbb{R}$$
Can we say anything about the limit
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)g(x)}{x}=\ ?$$
You can assume that the functions are differentiable if that helps. Are the three limits independent (in the sense that we need more information about the two functions to answer the question)?

Comment: I observe that the first two limits are blind to the signs of $f$ and $g$ in a neighborhood of $0$, so they don't even tell you the sign of your third limit (if that limit exists).

Comment: I see. However, the nature of the problem in which I encountered the limits implies that the third limit exists and is a real number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first limit, $l_1$ must be zero, since $f(x)^2/x$ is nonnegative for $x > 0$ and nonpositive for $x<0$. And then that limit contains very little information about how fast $f(x)$ actually tends to zero; it could be like $f(x) \sim |x|^{3/4}$ or $f(x) \sim c x$ or $f(x) \sim x^{1000}$. Coupled with the fact that $g(x)$ must tend to $1$ or $-1$ for the second limit to exist, this implies that we can't conclude anything about the third limit.

Comment: Oh, what an overlook, you are right. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The first limit doesn't exist unless it's in an indeterminte form. This means $f(0)=0$ else the limit wouldn't exist. By L'hopital's Rule, the limit must be  $2f'(0)f(0)=l_1$. So $l_1=0$.

By similar arguments  $g(0)^2=1$. $-2g'(0)g(0)=\mp 2g'(0)=l_2$

The third limit only exists if $f(0)g(0)=0$ and it has to be $l_3=f(0)g'(0)+f'(0)g(0)=0\cdot g'(0) \pm f'(0)=\pm f'(0)$.

So we don't know anything about $f'(0)$ and thus we know nothing about $l_3$.

So most we can say is $l_3=f'(0)$.So we don't know much.